# Disadvantages of Mean Squared Error?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, loss-function, autoencoder

I'm using **mean squared error** as **reconstruction** **error** for my autoencoder. The dataset is ECG (time series) and model is conv1d.

I assumed MSE as the best option for reconstruction error, but it's failing sometimes. What can be the plausible reasons for it not working.

In general when does MSE doesn't works or what are the **disadvantages** of MSE.

Please answer in general scenario as well as my specific case.